# Querying _Click data for link aliases

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

Links in my email contain aliases which I would like to query (for statistical purposes), in Email Studio > Tracking > Sends I can quite clearly see that the aliases are working as the link overview refers to the alias name instead of the URL itself.

When I query the `_Click` [data view](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_click.htm&type=5) and store `URL`, `LinkName` and `LinkContent`, neither of these contain the alias value.

Can someone tell me how to correctly get this information?

This is the query I have been using:

```
select 
JobID
, SubscriberID
, SubscriberKey
, EventDate
, Domain
, URL
, LinkName
, LinkContent
from _Click
```

Answer (score 6):

`LinkName` contains the alias value.

**Update**

Details about the `LinkName` are outlined on the [**Personalization String page**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5) in the official documentation -- in addition to the [**_Click data view page**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_click.htm&type=5) you referenced.

What you're doing is correct.  As to why it's not showing, I'd start with reviewing the alias values in your email code.  There are some limitations of using dynamic alias values.

Comment: Can you add a bit of detail here? I know linking to documentation isn't always possible with MC, but you're basically just contradicting the OP here (they claim the field doesn't contain the alias).

Comment: Yes, of course.  It was a half-asleep answer from my couch.

Comment: Hey @AdamSpriggs, the aliases I believe are set correctly as they are shown in the Link Overview page in my tracking instead of the full URL, it’s only when I expand the clicks on this link am I shown the URL.

Comment: The aliases are not dynamic, and are literal strings in our `<a>` tags

Comment: How you are you validating the missing alias values?  Your query is looking at every click in the last 6 months.  Wouldn't you want to look at a specific JobID?

Comment: I am actually filtering by a particular subscriberKey in my query, so its not environment specific I have removed this line in my post. I can see that the query does return the correct record from my Send History, but it does not populate the `LinkName`, as mentioned I can see the link alias used in the Click History for the same job so its definitely working.