# Duplicate Email Address, One Clicks but all records appear when querying _Click Data View

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, data-views

I have a requirement whereby a store owner may receive an email offer for every store they own, even though they have just one email address.  To get around the duplication issue we marked both the Email Address and the StoreID as Primary Keys and the emails deploy separately and are tracked as such through the Journey.

When we query the _Click data view to pull records that clicked in the email, if a store owner who shares their email address across locations clicks for only one store, all records appear in the results.

We tried adding a dynamic Alias (the Store ID), but we are not seeing any results in the data extension.

Did some digging here, and found this:
[Querying _Click data for link aliases] [Querying _Click data for link aliases](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/211098/querying-click-data-for-link-aliases)
but no luck.

Little help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the initial trial worked, but we queried the _Click table too soon.

What's strange is our URL appears as the AMPscript placeholder in _Click, but the Alias appears as the Store ID.  I've attached a screenshot of that here.

While this is our first email using this template, in the future we'd like to have the actual URL appear in _Click so we don't accidentally select those who clicked the template from a previous campaign.

[image: Link Name is OK, URL is not]